# functions body run as many times as I present ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I'm really confused.

I have function for listen socket.io emit from server side in my ViewController.
after i first time open the view controller and get the message from server all things ok.
but when i open the ViewController(using present) for second time & get the message from server this method run actually two time & as many times as i present the ViewController.

my function is:

```
func sendMessageStatus() {
     var message_body: String!
     var send_time: String!
     var chat_user_id: UInt!
    let socket = SocketConfig.manager.defaultSocket
    socket.on("messageReceived") { (dataArray, ack) in
        let response = dataArray as NSArray
        for resp in response {
            let resp_dic = resp as! NSDictionary
            for z in resp_dic {
                if z.key as! String == "time_now" {
                    send_time = (z.value as! String)
                }
                if z.key as! String == "message_body" {
                    message_body = z.value as? String
                }
                if z.key as! String == "chat_id" {
                    chat_user_id = z.value as? UInt
                    self.chat_id = z.value as? UInt
                }
            }
        }
        // 0 user_id is the value for my id(i dont have my id and none of users id is 0 so i use this for know my messages)
        let message_object = Messages(user_id: 0, message: message_body, receive_time: send_time)
        if var items = messages_dic[chat_user_id] {
            items.append(message_object)
            messages_dic[chat_user_id] = items
        }
        else {
            messages_dic[chat_user_id] = [message_object]
        }
        self.chatTableview.reloadData()
        self.scrollToBottom(animated: true, delay: 0.3)
    }

}
```

and this append to my messages_dic as many times as present the ViewController.

any one can help to solve this?
thank's.

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak. Make sure you don't have any strong reference cycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem.

the problem is each time that i present the ViewController
socket.on("messageReceived") 
set again and surely run as many times as i present the ViewController.

so for solve the problem I use the socket handlers for check if I handle "messageReceived" (set socket.on) don't set again.
so I use this code and the problem solved.

```
    var is_set: Bool = false
    let socket = SocketConfig.manager.defaultSocket
    for handler in socket.handlers {
        if handler.event ==  "messageReceived" {
            is_set = true
        }
    }
    if !is_set { // so set that
    socket.on("messageReceived") { (dataArray, ack) in 
     // othere codes
  }
```

and the another way is when I dismiss the ViewController I remove all handlers by this code:

```
 deinit() {
     let socket = SocketConfig.manager.defaultSocket
    socket.removeAllHandlers()
 }
```

hope to help someone.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say without seeing the code for your ViewController, but I would guess if is emitting `"messageReceived"` more frequently than you think. Perhaps is in is a `document.ready()` function or some other function. Your code here seems alright from a quick glance.

Comment: I really confused & don't know what to do.
thank's for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As one commenter suggested, you probably have a memory leak. Your ViewController is probably not getting released properly.

I would suggest using `[weak self]` in your socket closure:

```
socket.on("messageReceived") { [weak self] (dataArray, ack) in
```

Then within your socket closure, replace `self` with `self?`. For example:

```
self?.chatTableview.reloadData()
```

Comment: dear Mike Taverne thank's for answer.
I do this but in doesn't work.